The air in my 2012 Chevy Cruz LT stopped working all together?
I drive a 2012 Chevy Cruze LT, and just recently my air stopped working all together, ac button off, all the way from hot to cold, nothing's working, I checked the fuse and that looks fine, anything else it could be? I turned my car off and on after I noticed it and it worked, but after a few hours of my car being off it wasn't working again.
